# css: с помощью grid сделать так, чтобы первая ячейка по высоте равнялась всем строкам

Tags: html, css, css3, css-grid

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно с помощью `grid` сделать так, чтобы первая ячейка была в первом столбце и занимала по высоте все возможные строки (их кол-во может быть произвольным)

Т.е. если таблица содержит 2 строки, то и первая ячейка по высоте будет занимать обе строки, если таблица содержит 10 строк, то первая ячейка по высоте будет занимать 10 строк и т.д., но кол-во строк не статично (например, может быть добавлено динамически за счет добавления новых `<div>`)

```
.table {
    display:    grid;

    grid-template-columns:  repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-gap:               10px;

    width:      80vw;
    height:     80vh;

    border:     1px solid black;
}

.table div {
    background: red;
}

.table .header {
    grid-column:    1;
    grid-row:       1 / all; /* просто показал, что хочу с 1 строки и до последней */

    background: lime;
}
```

и

```
<div class = 'table'>
    <div class = 'header'></div>
    <div></div>
```

...

Comment: В чем проблема сделать 2 основных столбца, а
второй в себе сдержит вложенные строки

Comment: @ Sergei Dimitriev, так и сделал, но думал, что можно как-то не плодить лишних сущностей типа лишних `div`